# raspberry pi3B+で使っているmicroSDカードをraspberry pi4に差してそのまま起動するか？

Tags: raspberry-pi

Raspberry pi3B+を使用したシステムがあります。
故障等が発生した時のために予備機を準備することになりましたが、
昨今の半導体不足の影響で同じモデルのRaspberry piが入手しにくい状況です。

Raspberry pi4や3Bなら入手できそうなのですが、
Raspberry pi3B+のmicroSDをコピーしてそのまま使えるものなのでしょうか？

色々なサイトを調べてみましたが、回答を見つけられず、ご存じの方がおられたらご教授頂けないでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Raspberry Pi 3B+と4とZero WH(とPico)を所有していますが、Raspberry Pi OSの入ったmicroSDを相互に差し替えても問題なく動作します。(Picoは除く)

申し添えるならばRaspberry Pi 4とZero WHはスペックに大きな差がありますので、起動時にメモリ負荷が高い処理を流すプログラムなどを実行するようにcrontabなどを仕込んでいると、低スペック機では落ちる可能性があるかもしれません。

なお、Raspberry Pi OSはSDカードを読み取り専用にする[Overlay FS](https://www.google.com/amp/s/astherier.com/blog/2020/05/change-raspi-to-read-only/amp/)設定が簡単にできます。
この設定によってOS自体も書き込みができなくなりますので、どの機体を使っても絶対にSDカードの状態を変更できなくすることも可能です。

Answer (score 2):

##### OSとして

Raspberry Pi OSは, 32bit版であれば
おおよそそのままで他の Raspberry Pi でも動きます (Pi Zeroでデスクトップ版とか無茶しない限り)
(Raspberry Pi 3B, Raspberry Pi 4B 間の 64bit同士でも同様)

[image: Raspberry Pi OS 選択]

Ubuntu や Manjaro の場合も, "(RPi 3/4)" を含むものなら,
Raspberry Pi 3,4 共通で動かせます

[image: Ubuntu 選択]
[image: Manjaro 選択]

##### 何らかのライブラリー / インターフェース

現在の Raspberry Pi OSは Debian Bullseyeをベースとしていて, 新しいバージョンのライブラリと新しいインターフェースが付属し旧いインターフェースはサポートされません

"Raspberry Pi OS (Legacy)" であれば, 当分は Debian Buster ベースのライブラリー / インターフェースを使い続けることが可能。(kernelも)
(予定では 2024年6月まで)

(期間的に余裕はあるけれど), (なるべく)旧い API / ライブラリーに依存しないようにメンテナンスが必要になるかも

参考:
(raspberrypi.com) [“New” old functionality with Raspberry Pi OS (Legacy)](https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/new-old-functionality-with-raspberry-pi-os-legacy/)

---

#### 追記

上記 OSについての項目は, 回答投稿時のインストール可能な OS(の一部)ですが

それと同時に, Raspberry Pi 3B にインストールした可能性の高い OS でもあり,
(もしも使用中のが) Debian Buster ベースの OSならば, "Raspberry Pi OS (Legacy)" と同等か ほぼ同等と思われます
(質問に記されていなかったので,)

セキュリティーやバグフィックスの問題もあり
またハードも多少異なるところもあるので, 実際には Raspberry Pi 4B では "Raspberry Pi OS (Legacy)" もしくは Debian Bullseyeベースのものにして, アプリを乗っけてテスト -- 動作確認してみるのがよいのではないかと

Comment: 例えばシリアル通信などでは, ハード的に少し変化があるので考慮の必要があります
https://www.ingenious.jp/articles/howto/raspberry-pi-howto/gpio-uart/